# JD 6415 diesel engine not starting after fuel injector replacement

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, fuel-injection, tractor

This tractor has an inline 4 cylinder fuel injected turbocharged diesel engine. The injectors are pencil-stick style.
The original reason why the fuel injectors were replaced is due to excessive fuel leaking from the injectors, which both wastes fuel and creates potential fire hazard.
We replaced the old injectors with what we believe are equivalents (the new and old look identical).
The only leaking now is very minor, if nonexistent.
Immediately after the replacement, the tractor started fine.
After sitting for a few moments, it wouldn't start. We both put starting fluid and gas soaked rag over the intake, which allowed it to run, but not very well at all, likely wasn't even burning diesel. We then bled it, and a little air came out, but it still didn't start. We are pretty lost at what could be wrong. I hope you can be helpful, thank you and have a nice day.

Note: We don't know the exact year, but we think it is around 2009.

Comment: The numbers for those injectors are usually along the body. Did you check once the old ones were out? The numbers will show any difference once looked up. Have you tried refitting the old ones to see if it runs?

Comment: No, one of the old ones broke during removal.

Comment: And did you check what I asked first?

Comment: We are about to go to where the tractor is to continue working on it.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say the fuel system needs to bled more completely.

Comment: The numbers match, and we tried to bleed it more completely by loosening the fittings on the injector.